# Is there a way to define pure SQL UDF's that still take advantage of all of Pyspark's optimizations?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm repeating a lot of code that looks like the following:

```
trim(concat(ifnull(`field1`, ''), ' ', ifnull(`field2`, ''))) as my_field
```

It would be nice to be able to define a function called `trim_and_concat` that takes an arbitrary number of fields, concatenates them, and trims the result. I could write a UDF, but then I would lose out on all the PySpark optimization.

**Is it possible to define a function that combines native SparkSQL methods such that the typical loss of opitimization associated with UDFs is avoided?**

I know about the [`create_function`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html) syntax, but as far as I can tell this is just another way to create UDFs, and still requires that the functions be written in scala or Python.

Answer (score 0):

the easier way to go is defining a function with all transformation needed:

```py
def trim_and_concat(columns):
    all_columns = []
    for col in columns:
        all_columns.append(ifnull(col))
        all_columns.append(lit(' '))
        
    return trim(concat(*all_columns))

df = df.withColumn('test', trim_and_concat(['field1', 'field2']))
```